# Can overwriting 0 still keep copy-on-write?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmap, copy-on-write

In a [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) system, reading does not increase memory, while writing data brings in new pages. And OS also has zero pages, mmap memory addresses would have 0 provided by zero page, and reading 0 from them does not increase memory until we write. But overwriting 0 on those mmap-ed addresses increases memory. Is it possible to still keep copy-on-write and use zero pages after overwriting 0?

Comment: If I well understand, you say that writing 0 over an existing 0 still does copy-on-write. I would say this is the expected behavior: a write is a write...

Comment: In order for the page fault code to tell that you are only writing 0 to the zero page, it would have to do some deep inspection of the faulting instruction and its operands.